# PeerToPeer data transfer with CUDA graphs

Tags: c++, cuda, memcpy

Utilizing CUDA Graphs, I want to transfer some data from one GPU to the other one via NVLink. After defining the graph and nodes, I am populating the `memcpy` parameters as following to transfer from GPU 0 to 1:

```c
cudaMemcpy3DPeerParms memcpyParams = {0};

memset(&memcpyParams, 0, sizeof(memcpyParams));
memcpyParams.srcDevice = 0;
memcpyParams.srcArray = NULL;
memcpyParams.srcPos = make_cudaPos(0, 0, 0);
memcpyParams.srcPtr =
  make_cudaPitchedPtr((void *)d_inputs[0], data_size, data_count, 1);
memcpyParams.dstDevice = 1;
memcpyParams.dstArray = NULL;
memcpyParams.dstPos = make_cudaPos(0, 0, 0);
memcpyParams.dstPtr =
  make_cudaPitchedPtr(d_results[1], data_size, data_count, 1);
memcpyParams.extent = make_cudaExtent(data_size, 1, 1);

// Add the first copy node with no dependency
cudaGraphAddMemcpyNode(&copy_0to1, graph, NULL, 0, &memcpyParams);
```

The compiler doesn't like the last parameter of the `cudaGraphAddMemcpyNode`. It says:

> error: argument of type "cudaMemcpy3DPeerParms *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const cudaMemcpy3DParms *"

Static conversion of the structures doesn't work, and they have different parameters too. From driver headerfile:

```c
/**
 * CUDA 3D memory copying parameters
 */
struct __device_builtin__ cudaMemcpy3DParms
{
    cudaArray_t            srcArray;  /**< Source memory address */
    struct cudaPos         srcPos;    /**< Source position offset */
    struct cudaPitchedPtr  srcPtr;    /**< Pitched source memory address */
  
    cudaArray_t            dstArray;  /**< Destination memory address */
    struct cudaPos         dstPos;    /**< Destination position offset */
    struct cudaPitchedPtr  dstPtr;    /**< Pitched destination memory address */
  
    struct cudaExtent      extent;    /**< Requested memory copy size */
    enum cudaMemcpyKind    kind;      /**< Type of transfer */
};

/**
 * CUDA 3D cross-device memory copying parameters
 */
struct __device_builtin__ cudaMemcpy3DPeerParms
{
    cudaArray_t            srcArray;  /**< Source memory address */
    struct cudaPos         srcPos;    /**< Source position offset */
    struct cudaPitchedPtr  srcPtr;    /**< Pitched source memory address */
    int                    srcDevice; /**< Source device */
  
    cudaArray_t            dstArray;  /**< Destination memory address */
    struct cudaPos         dstPos;    /**< Destination position offset */
    struct cudaPitchedPtr  dstPtr;    /**< Pitched destination memory address */
    int                    dstDevice; /**< Destination device */
  
    struct cudaExtent      extent;    /**< Requested memory copy size */
};
```

It seems to me that there are no functions like `cudaGraphAddMemcpyNode` that accept `cudaMemcpy3DPeerParms` arguments. So, how can I send a piece of data from one GPU to its peer directly using NVLink in CUDA graphs?!

Comment: Did you try cudaMemcpy3Params with transfer type set to `cudaMemcpyDefault` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Abator commented, using `cudaMemcpyDefault` with `cudaMemcpy3Params` worked:

```c
cudaMemcpy3DParms memcpyParams = {0};

memset(&memcpyParams, 0, sizeof(memcpyParams));
memcpyParams.srcArray = NULL;
memcpyParams.srcPos = make_cudaPos(0, 0, 0);
memcpyParams.srcPtr =
  make_cudaPitchedPtr((void *)d_inputs[0], data_size, data_count, 1);

memcpyParams.dstArray = NULL;
memcpyParams.dstPos = make_cudaPos(0, 0, 0);
memcpyParams.dstPtr =
  make_cudaPitchedPtr(d_results[1], data_size, data_count, 1);
memcpyParams.extent = make_cudaExtent(data_size, 1, 1);
memcpyParams.kind = cudaMemcpyDefault;
```

As mentioned in `driver_types.h`: Direction of the transfer is inferred from the pointer values. Requires unified virtual addressing